# Adjusting UIImage size Placed in a UITableView's Header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set an image as a `UITableView`'s header, though the header's size won't adjust to the size of the image. Based upon much research (see my edits) the relevant code I'm using to achieve this is as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 150)
    let headerImageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "reminder3.png")!
    headerImageView.image = image
    return headerImageView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 150
}
```

It adds the image to the header, and I can adjust the headers size, but no matter what I set as the height value (currently 300) it always remains at a constant size. The default-looking header size. I cannot get the header to adjust to match the size of my `UIImage`. So, I tried adding this method:
 Does anyone know a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: You want the tableView header to adjust to your UIImage height (which is not 300)?

Comment: Exactly, I was using the 300 value as a tester

Comment: Ok so you can create the UIImage and then ask for its size (image.size) and then create the tableView header with that size. No need to use the delegate method.

Comment: @Plasher I've tried that, though it did not work. Or at least I think I tried what you are describing, would you mind explaining more or showing how the code above is broken? I updated it after more research and attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat` instead, like this:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "image")!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIImageView(image: img)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let w = view.frame.size.width
    let imgw = img.size.width
    let imgh = img.size.height
    return w/imgw*imgh
}
```

Only use `estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection` when you don't know exact height, it is primarily used for determining the scrollbar position of UITableView.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation and sample code!

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Create the UIImage
    let image = UIImage(named: "testing")

    //Check its size
    print(image?.size)

    //Create the UIImageView that will be our headerView with the table width
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.tableView.bounds.width, height: image!.size.height))

    //Set the image
    imageView.image = image

    //Clips to bounds so the image doesnt go over the image size
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    //Scale aspect fill so the image doesn't break the aspect ratio to fill in the header (it will zoom)
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill

    //Set the tableHeaderView
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = imageView
}
```

I strongly recommend you use UIImage extension with an AssetIdentifier enum to create an UIImage with name and be type-safe as they recommend on WWDC2015.